# How to launch (when the app is not running) or switch (when the app is running) to an android app when clicking a link

Tags: android

My app (a game) has two activities: a launcher activity which shows logo, does initializations and is the main activity of my app, and a client activity which does the 3D rendering and is started by the launcher activity. Thus when the app is running, the back stack is: launcher | client.

What I want with a link is:

1. if the app has not been started, clicking the link should first start the launcher activity, then the launcher activity start the client activity. Finally the game runs in the client activity.
2. if the app is running (running in the client activity), clicking the link should switch to and notify the app that the link is clicked (either in launcher or client is ok, better in client), instead of starting another launcher activity.

What I have tried:

1. I added an intent filter in the declaration of the launcher acitivity:

   ```
   <activity android:name=".Launcher" android:label="TestApp">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>

       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <data android:scheme="myapp" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>

   <activity android:name=".Client" android:label="TestApp">
   </activity>
   ```

   And the intent filter works when I click the link: myapp://, the launcher activity is started. But the problem is the launcher activity is started in the browser's task. If I already have an app running, there will be a new instance of my app started in the browers back stack, instead of switching to the already running app.
2. Then I tried add the attribute `android:launchMode="singleTask"` into the activity declaration. Then clicking the link will start a new task and the Launcher activity is started in that task. And if the app has already running, the running task is switched to foreground, that's what I expect. But the problem is, the back stack of the app task is changed from "launcher | client" to "launcher", the client activity is gone.

I hope that there is only one instance of my app. Cliking a link should start the app if the app is not running, otherwise switch to the app without affecting the app's current running states.

I searched a lot but don't find a solution, please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html) for app links assistant

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I think I have manually done all these steps in the links assistant, as in my post, and it didn't solve the problem.